# Prove that $P_{x}(T_{y}\leq n+1) = P(x,y) +\sum_{z\neq y}P(x,z)P_{z}(T_{y}\leq n) $

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $T_{y} = \min\{ n\geq 0 : X_{n}=y \}$ and $P_{x}( A )$ be the probability of the event $A$ given that the Markov chain starts at $x$.
I want to prove that
$$P_{x}(T_{y}\leq n+1) = P(x,y) +\sum_{z\neq y}P(x,z)P_{z}(T_{y}\leq n) $$ using that I know that
$$P_{x}(T_{y}=n+1) = \sum_{z\neq y}P(x,z)P_{z}(T_{y}=n)$$

But I don't know how to do it. Do you know how to prove it?   thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want $T_y:=\min\{n\ge 1: X_n=y\}$ instead? Else your formula is incorrect — you're neglecting the possibility that. $y=x$ in which case $P_x(T_y=0)=1$ with the present definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition on $X_1$ and use the Markov property to get for $x\neq y$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}P_x(T_y\leq n+1)&=& P(T_y\leq n+1|X_0=x) \\ &=& \sum_{z} P(T_y\leq n+1| X_0=x,X_1=z) P(X_1=z|X_0=x) \\ &=&  P(T_y\leq n+1|X_0=x,X_1=y)P(X_1=y|X_0=x) + \sum_{z\neq y} P(T_y\leq n+1|X_0=x,X_1=z)P(X_1=z|X_0=x) \\ &=& 1\cdot P(X_1=y|X_0=x)+\sum_{z\neq y}P(T_y \leq n+1|X_1=z)P(X_1=z|X_0=x) \\ &=& P(X_1=y|X_0=x)+\sum_{z\neq y}P(T_y \leq n|X_0=z)P(X_1=z|X_0=x) \\&=&  P(x,y)+\sum_{z\neq y}P_z(T_y \leq n)P(x,z)  \end{eqnarray*}$$ Note $P_y(Y_y\leq n)$ should really be $P_z(T_y\leq n)$. As a matter of fact, $P_y(T_y\leq n)=1$.